Rust Iterate through a vector of string and mutate the contents
I am a newbie in Rust. I want to iterate through a vector of String and modify the values. How will one do it? Below is the code I wrote, but it fails.
let mut val: [&str; 3] = ["Hello", "Hi", "Hey"];
for value in val.iter_mut() {
    *value = *value + "a";
    println!("{}", value);
}

Say I just want to add the letter "a" to each of the elements in val.

If you're constructing strings at run-time, they have to be String, e.g.: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7e1378fdf47cac9704b97d7b331be83f

Does this answer your question? How do I concatenate strings?

fn main() {
    let mut val: [String; 3] = ["Hello".to_string(), "Hi".to_string(), "Hey".to_string()];
    val.iter_mut().for_each(|s| s.push('a'));
    println!("{val:#?}");
}

